# Trying to install Magento 2.3.6 - error Class Magento\GoogleShoppingAds\Model\Cache\Type does not exist

Tags: magento2

I am trying to run a magento install script (using deployer). The exact same script on exact same git branch works on another machine.

This is the error:

```
✔ Executing task deploy:prepare
✔ Executing task deploy:lock
✔ Executing task deploy:release
✔ Executing task deploy:update_code
✔ Executing task deploy:shared
✔ Executing task deploy:vendors
✔ Executing task mydebug
✔ Executing task deploy:clear_paths
✔ Executing task magento:setup:permissions
➤ Executing task magento:config
✔ Executing task deploy:failed
✔ Executing task deploy:unlock

In Client.php line 103: The command "cd /home/justadev/public_html/releases/20210226153919/ && /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/bin/n98-magerun2 cache:enable --quiet" failed.                                                              
                                                                                                                                   
  In ClassReader.php line 26:       
    Class Magento\GoogleShoppingAds\Model\Cache\Type does not exist
```

My previous release was using Magento 2.3.3, in this release I am trying to upgrade to Magento 2.3.6

The deploy script (with Magento 2.3.6) is also working on another server. I tried to disable the Magento_GoogleShoppingAds from `app/etc/config.php` and also remove it completely. It doesn't help.

I don't see this GoogleShoppingAds anywhere in my code. When I do `bin/magento module:status` it is in the disabled section. Where it is coming from and how can I remove it?

## UPDATE

same issue happens with normal magento cache:flash

```
$ bin/magento cache:flush

In ClassReader.php line 26:
                                                                   
  Class Magento\GoogleShoppingAds\Model\Cache\Type does not exist
```

I added `"magento/google-shopping-ads":"4.0.1"` to composer.json, and I see that composer did install it:

```
$ ll vendor/magento/google-shopping-ads/
total 12
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 myuser myuser 691 Jun  1  2020 composer.json
drwxr-xr-x. 2 myuser myuser  41 Feb 26 16:11 etc
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 myuser myuser 218 Jun  1  2020 README.md
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 myuser myuser 274 Jun  1  2020 registration.php
drwxr-xr-x. 2 myuser myuser  50 Feb 26 16:11 Setup
```

However the issue is still happening.

Comment: Same setup, same upgrade, same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Yes. Removing the (redis) cache helped in my case

Comment: When you say "removing", you mean "purging". Right?

Comment: At the moment I really disabled the cache from env.php because I didn't had redis permissions on that server. I will need to get back to this issue soon as now redis is ok. Try purging, I hope that it works as well

Comment: You're right! It made the trick. Gonna post my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errors like `Class Magento\ModuleName\Model\Cache\Type does not exist` are usually related to cache.

I had exactly the same issue. The deployments were failing even purging all caches just before.

Disabling or removing Redis permanently is a bad idea. The negative impact on performance might be really really high.

To bypass this situation and complete the deployment, I followed this steps:

1. Open the `app/etc/env.php` file with any text editor.
2. Comment the lines related to the Redis setup. They start with the `'cache'` key (More info [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/redis/redis-pg-cache.html#results)).
3. Save the changes.
4. Retry the deployment. In my case (Or yours if you are using Deployer.org), `dep -v deploy production`. The stage name `production` could be different according to your setup.
5. If your release was successfully deployed, open the `app/etc/env.php` more one time and revert the changes made in step 2.
6. Save the changes and purge all caches (Via adminhtml or CLI using `bin/magento c:c && bin/magento c:f`).

Everything should be working as expected, including Redis.